# Sobre questões de escopo amplo

Tags: debate

Em minha [última pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269/quais-as-vantagens-das-expressoes-lambda-presentes-no-java-8) minha intenção era deixar alguma informação útil e resumida sobre uma funcionalidade importante de uma linguagem importante. Minha expectativa era alguma resposta no [estilo](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/a/633) que usuários como o @CodeGnome deixam no pm.stackexchange.com.

Note que eu não queria que ninguém me ensinasse, já que em 10 segundos eu abro o Google e encontro a documentação oficial ou um bom tutorial. Acredito que alguns tenham interpretado a pergunta da seguinte forma: "eu tenho preguiça de ler e quero que alguém me ensine esse negócio todo". Outros assim: "me expliquem esse treco nos mínimos detalhes". Por outro lado, alguns usuários conseguiram responder de forma concisa.

Outros objetivos secundário eram:

1. Testar como esse tipo de pergunta seria recebida, o que vejo que não ocorreu muito bem.
2. Obter, além da simples definição do conceito, uma análise crítica das pessoas envolvidas. Esse objetivo foi alcançado, pois acredito que a análise do usuário @dstori sobre o assunto (e também a contribuição de outros) tenha ascresentado um ponto de vista interessante.

Pessoalmente, ainda não peguei muito o "espírito" do pessoal aqui no br.SO, mas vou acompanhando para ver como as coisas ficam.

E uma observação final quanto ao assunto que se aplica principalmente enquanto o site estiver na fase beta: embora a pergunta não tenha sido bem aceita como foi formulada, independente do motivo, seria melhor pedir que ela fosse ajustada antes de sair respondendo. Eu entendo perfeitamente que é ruim perder aquele "momento" em que queremos responder e parar para solicitar um esclarecimento ou ajuste. Mas às vezes é melhor pedir ao autor da pergunta para diminuir ou escopo, esclarecer melhor a intenção da pergunta ou então ser mais objetivo, pois nem sempre é possível mensurar como diversas pessoas com culturas diferentes irão interpretá-la.

Enfim, alguém acha que a pergunta deve ser excluída? Alguém acha que ela serve para alguma coisa ou tem alguma sugestão de como ela poderia ser feita de forma a ser útil e atrair visitantes para o site?

Comment: Ninguém pegou o espírito ainda :) E ele pode mudar de hoje para amanhã. Estamos vendo o que é bom e o que não. E lembre-se que a pergunta pode ser reaberta a qualquer momento, depende mais de você.

Comment: Esta já tem cabelo @Earendul :D

Comment: @JorgeB. Estava a caça da medalha escavador, ;)

Answer (score 7):

Eu pessoalmente gosto desse tipo de pergunta, mas vai contra a linha geral do stack overflow original. Se deve ser aceita ou não em português, não vou me meter.

Mas existe uma forma de reformular a pergunta para deixa-la não ambígua: perguntar quais justificativas levaram a inclusão dessa característica na linguagem Java.

Comment: +1. Está cada vez mais claro que aqui aceitará perguntas "proibidas" no SO original, mas elas precisam ser bem escritas para que possa haver uma *resposta* e não um discurso ou um capítulo de um livro.

Comment: +1 Acredito que sim, deixando justificativas sobre o porquê de existir a pergunta pode ajudar muito a evitar essas confusões de perguntas amplas

Comment: Sobre o "não vou me meter", como somos os poucos primeiros usuários, o que for decidido explícita ou implicitamente no começo vai ter um impacto grande sobre o futuro do site, então acho importante, sim, que todos se metam e ajudem a pensar as questões mais polêmicas. Senão, corremos o risco de delegá-las a quem tem "mais tempo a perder com isso", que nem sempre são os melhores representantes da vontade da comunidade.

Answer (score 0):

Eu concordo com o que o @utluiz descreveu, muitas vezes as perguntas acabam ficando com o escopo grande porque o próprio dono da pergunta não tem o conhecimento do assunto para saber qual o tamanho.

Answer (score -1):

**A questão que eu tenho sobre o Java 8 é se o Lambda realmente melhora a vida dos programadores?** Ela facilita a vida dos programadores em certas situações, mas a linguagem Java está começando a ficar difícil de ler. E quanto mais difícil de ler, mais fácil de aparecerem bugs que alguém não perceberia numa revisão de código. Quanto mais complexa fica a linguagem, mais difícil para a pessoas dominarem ela corretamente, ou seja, mais bugs.

Mas é complicado colocar uma questão dessas no StackOverflow, ou ela é muito ampla, ou é muito específica. **Talvez a verdade seja que o StackOverflow não serve para questões complexas.**

Comment: O SO não funciona bem para discussões (pode funcionar quando ela é muito bem direcionada e permite *alguma* objetividade), principalmente aquelas que levam as pessoas fazerem discurso sobre o tema :P Até porque tem perguntas que dão muita coceira para fazer isso. Por outro lado também não funciona quando um capítulo de um livro é necessário para "responder".

Comment: Isso porque a gente responde partindo do princípio que as pessoas entendem do assunto. Os grandes discursos aparecem quando você opta por explicar por completo. As vezes somos mais filósofos do que tecnólogos, o que deve ser o motivo de criarem [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Isso foi falado ontem no chat, somos mesmo :) O motivo da criação do P.SE é mais complexa, mas de certa forma ele acaba aceitando um pouco mais questões subjetivas. Mas não qualquer uma, Por isso é o site que tem maior índice de fechamento de questões.